# How many integers are divisible by at least one of the numbers $4$,$ 7$ and $33$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion, totient-function

Find how many integers $N$ satisfying $1≤n≤5000$ are divisible by at least one of the numbers $4$, $7$ and $33$ ?

---

I did solve this by using Inclusion - Exclusion and got correct but by using Euler's Totient Function, I not not able to get correct one.

Such numbers will be total 5000 - $φ(5000)$.

Hence, $φ(5000)$ = $2^3.5^4$ = $2000$

---

Well, Where am I wrong here ?

Comment: why and how totient function??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The totient function you've computed is correct, but completely unrelated to the problem at hand.

$\phi(5000)$ answers the question: how many numbers $n\leq 5000$ are relatively prime to $5000$?  It has nothing to do with the 4, 7, or 33 stated in your question.

Comment: But using the same method, I got correct here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065494/how-many-numbers-less-than-or-equal-to-120-are-divisible-by-2-3-or-5

Comment: That would be because $2,3,5$ are precisely the primes that divide $120$ -- and therefore being relatively prime to $120$ is identical to being divisible by none of $2$, $3$, and $5$.

Comment: AND you were trying to find the number of factors which are divisible by NONE of them, as opposed to at least one.

Comment: Okk !! I am getting factors in 2 and 5 whereas problem asks for 4,7,33.And in that question, I have got the factors exactly in the 2,3 and 5 which is actually the problem asking. Have I got it right now ?

Comment: Seems so, yes. :-)

Comment: Thanks for clarification :-)